# How do I debug pulseaudio skipping problems?

Tags: linux, debugging, firefox, audio, pulseaudio

I am experiencing intermittent audio skipping problems with Youtube's HTML5 video player in Firefox 5.0 on Fedora 15. I've had audio problems with pulseaudio for years. I would like to try and debug this particular issue, since I've removed proprietary Flash from the picture, so only open source code should be relevant now.

However, I have no idea how to get started - beyond looking in dmesg and /var/log/messages. dmesg has nothing relevant; /var/log/messages shows:

```
Jul 30 14:42:18 natgreen pulseaudio[2151]: ratelimit.c: 533 events suppressed
Jul 30 14:44:43 natgreen pulseaudio[2151]: ratelimit.c: 266 events suppressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Killing pulseaudio and starting it with `--log-level=debug` may help. However, pulseaudio might restart automatically when you kill it (in fact I think that it was it is supposed to do), so it might be a bit more complicated than that...